# How to reset the login password of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: passwords, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I forgot the login password for Apache IoTDB and I cannot startup IoTDB normally. I want to know how to reset this password without starting IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you restart the service of Apache IoTDB? You can replace this file in the currently running instance with the `root.profile file` in a newly launched instance, and see if when starting this instance, you can correct your IoTDB password.